# Exclude total page count

Tags: page-numbering, auxiliary-files

First two page contain some title page image it should not count as part of first page count and also exclude in total page count. Is that possible to update through `.aux` file?

`filenamenew_pgcount.xml` output should be

Required Output:

```
<fpage>101</fpage> <lpage>103</lpage> <tpage>3</tpage>
```

Current Output:

```
<fpage>3</fpage> <lpage>103</lpage> <tpage>5</tpage>
```

Please find MWE file as follows:

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{zref-totpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcounter{xmyFP}
\newcounter{xmyLP}
\newcommand\valxmyFP{\setcounter{xmyFP}{\thepage}}
\newcommand\valxmyLP{\setcounter{xmyLP}{\thepage}}

\newcommand\outputmetainfo{%
\newwrite\file
\immediate\openout\file=filenamenew_pgcount.xml\relax
\immediate\write\file{
<ArticleMetaData>
<PageCount Type="PageExtent">
<fpage>\arabic{xmyFP}</fpage>
<lpage>\arabic{xmyLP}</lpage>
<tpage>\ztotpages</tpage>
</PageCount>
</ArticleMetaData>
}
\closeout\file
}

\AtBeginDocument{%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight]{test-1.eps}
\clearpage
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight]{test-2.eps}
\clearpage
\valxmyFP
}

\AtEndDocument{\valxmyLP\outputmetainfo}

\newenvironment{body}{}{}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{101}

\begin{body}
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{body}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the "first page", since you are running `\valxmyFP` before you `\setcounter{page}{101}`, obviously it will pick up 3 and not 101. I am not quite sure what the purpose of your exercise is, but there are two possibilities to mind: (a) you can just move the `\setcounter` to before `\valxmyFP`. (b) you can use the hooks and call `\valxmyFP` not `\AtBeginDocument` but when you shipout the first page.

Comment: For the "total number", you could just call something like `\number\numexpr\ztotpages-2\relax` to subtract 2. If you don't want to hard-code two, I am sure that you can use `zref` to find the page number of the last "picture page" to subtract.